# how to get selected text in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am able to get the selected text of a webbrowser control in WPF by the following:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc1 = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
        IHTMLDocument3 doc = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument3;

        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = doc1.selection;

        if (doc1.selection.type == "Text")
        {
            IHTMLTxtRange range = (IHTMLTxtRange)doc1.selection.createRange();
        }
```

This works just fine and if I set the value of range.text to something else it changes the value of the text. The only issue I'm having is on web pages such as Gmail that have some kind of WYSIWYG editor on it, the selection.type is always 'None'. I suspect it is because the text editor is technically a child document. I'm not sure how to find child documents and check to see if text is selected. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could check if [document.activeElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a frame and has [contentWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property (`document.activeElement.contentWindow != null`) Then you could use `contentWindow.document` to get to the frame's inner `document`. Do this recursively until you find a frame with `document.selection != null`.

To illustrate this:

*main.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

*iframe.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    window.focus();
    document.execCommand("SelectAll", false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body contentEditable="true">
This is editable
</body>
```

C#:

```
var text = this.wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] {
    "document.activeElement.contentWindow.document.selection.createRange().text" });
MessageBox.Show(text.ToString());
```

Shows:

> This is editable